# How do I send JSon as BODY In a POST request to server from an Android application?

Tags: android, json, rest, post, seam

I am working on my first Android Application. What I am trying to do is  a POST request to a REST service I want the BODY of this request to be a JSON String.

I am using google's GSON to generate the JSON that is sent to the server. Here is the code doing POST request:

```
HttpPost requisicao = new HttpPost();
requisicao.setURI(new URI(uri));
requisicao.setHeader("User-Agent", sUserAgent);
requisicao.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
HttpResponse resposta = null;
//I can see the json correctly print on log with the following entry.
Log.d(TAG, "JSon String to send as body in this request ==>> " + jsonString);
//than I try to send JSon using setEntityMethod
StringEntity sEntity = new StringEntity(jsonString, "UTF-8");
requisicao.setEntity(sEntity);

resposta = httpClient.execute(requisicao);
resultado = HttpProxy.leRespostaServidor(resposta);
```

The response code is 400 BAD REQUEST and from the server log I can read the info. where it says the body was not correctly sent:

```
13:48:22,524 ERROR [SynchronousDispatcher] Failed executing POST /peso/cadastrar/maia.marcos@gmail.com
org.jboss.resteasy.spi.BadRequestException: Could not find message body reader for type: class java.io.Reader of content type: application/json
```

The code for the server side is a simple Seam Rest Service:

```
    @POST
 @Path("/cadastrar/{userEmail}")
 @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
 public String cadastraPeso(@PathParam("userEmail") String email, Reader jsonString)
 {
  LineNumberReader lnr = new LineNumberReader(jsonString);
  try {
   String json = lnr.readLine();
   if(json != null)
   {
    log.debug("String json recebida do device ==>> " + json);
   } 
  } catch (IOException e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
   return "OK - o e-mail processado foi ==>> " + email;
 }
```

What could be wrong with the Android client code? I have researched the web and did not find any really useful information about this error.

[]s

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sorry folks, just turned out that the error was on the Rest service. I had change it and now it receives a String instead of the Reader object and it works as expected, the REST endpoint code on the server side now is:

```
@POST
@Path("/cadastrar/{userEmail}")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String cadastraPeso(@PathParam("userEmail") String email, String jsonString)
{
        String json = jsonString;
        if(json != null)
        {
            log.debug("String json received from device ==>> " + json);
        }   
        return "OK - processed email ==>> " + email;
}
```

And the JSON string is correctly received on server side.

So de Android code above is working as expected.

Comment: Hi Arthur, I have to tell you I am still a bit lost using stack overflow. As a starter it looks too much information for me, I mean, all the mecanics on this points, comments, posts, as a first impression looks a bit confuse these forums, but I have found great information using it so I hope to get used quick.

Comment: I'm glad you find this site useful, but please accept your own answer as an accepted answer by clicking the icon below the down arrow. It will be highlighted as green when your mouse is over it.

Comment: @Shervin It looks like I have to wait a couple of days to be able to do that. Ill do it than.